# Google sheets, sort function

Tags: function, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to auto-sort through the script editor in Google Sheets. I have in my Google Sheets several columns:

```
+--------+------------+-------+--------+------------+
| Region |  Mag       | Comp  | Region |  Mag       |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+------------+
| A      | MIKA       | TRUE  | A      | MIKA       |
| B      | KALO       | FALSE | B      | NOKA       |
| C      | MINA       | FALSE | C      | South-East |
| D      | North      | TRUE  | D      | North      |
| B      | NOKA       | FALSE | B      | KALO       |
| C      | South-East | FALSE | C      | MINA       |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+------------+
```

I would like to match the two columns (Region, Mag) on the left with the two columns (Region, Mag) on the right, so in the end I would have my comparison column (which has a formula like `=exact(string1,string2)`) with `TRUE`s only.

I want to have a kind of button so that my two columns (Region, Mag) on the right of Comp could sort themselves.

I had this script, thanks to @JPV

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sort').addItem('Sort Col D and E', 'sort').addToUi();
}

function sort() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var srange = ss.getRange('A2:B7').getValues();
var trange = ss.getRange('D2:E7');
var trangeVal = trange.getValues();
var returnarr = [];
for (var i = 0, ilen = trangeVal.length; i < ilen; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, jlen = srange.length; j < jlen; j++) {
        if (trangeVal[i][0] == srange[j][0] && trangeVal[i][1] == srange[j][1]) {
            returnarr[j] = trangeVal[i];
        }
    }
}
trange.setValues(returnarr);
}
```

But seems not working and throwing an error like "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]"

Any help please!
Again thanks to @JPV

Comment: So sorry don't know how to ident my code. I have in fact 5 columns with 7 rows. Don't know how to write arrays here

Comment: Sharing a spreadsheet with some example data is also a good option.

Comment: I know I paste it in my post but seem don't know how to arrange it

Comment: My problem here is to have my comp column set to true. Can anybody help me to re arrange my array

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. I seem to have such problem always.

Comment: Don't understand how you want to sort. Let me explain a little bit. If I have for my second row B KALO B KALO, I would have my comp column set to TRUE.

Comment: It is actually a formula. If both my columns Mag are set to the same string, I would have True in my comp column

Comment: exact(string1,string2) simply

Comment: So, I want to have a kind of button so that my 2 columns (Region,Mag) in the right of comp could sort themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Maybe this script will help you ?

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sort').addItem('Sort Col D and E', 'sort').addToUi();
}

function sort() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var srange = ss.getRange('A2:B7').getValues();
var trange = ss.getRange('D2:E7');
var trangeVal = trange.getValues();
var returnarr = [];
for (var i = 0, ilen = trangeVal.length; i < ilen; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, jlen = srange.length; j < jlen; j++) {
        if (trangeVal[i][0] == srange[j][0] && trangeVal[i][1] == srange[j][1]) {
            returnarr[j] = trangeVal[i];
        }
    }
}
trange.setValues(returnarr);
}
```

Note: this will only work if the values in D&E are somewhere to be found in A&B. Also be aware of the fact that his will overwrite the values in D&E.

[Test sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ImL4m6c9BayEfHhKVgdWnHVzxmj5o1yW6XSGQ4Mwtw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hellp @JPV. sorry to keep bother you on this topic. But Can you explain a little bit this code. In fact, I run the function OnOpen which create the Menu sort. But when I click to the button sort , i run on this error     Cannot convert Array to Object[][]

Comment: Can you set up an example sheet with the code attached so I can have a look ?

Comment: I try the script with the same array i posted above. But it seeems not working, throwing an error "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]"

Comment: Hi again, I copied your example data and made a test sheet (added to the answer. I ran the script and it seemed to work.

Comment: Hi, your script works. Thanks Maybe, i run the function sort instead of OnOpen()